# perfect sequences

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation, correlation

I have heard somewhere that sequences with perfect autocorrelations and crosscorrelations do not exist. I have been searching for an insight into this claim, but have not been successful.

Can anyone can give a think about this and share his view? I have tried seeing previous questions but no luck there as well.

Comment: what do you mean by *"perfect"* with regard to autocorrelation?  there are repeating sequences of $x[n]=\pm1$, called **Maximum Length Sequences (MLS)** or **Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) sequences** or **PN sequences** or **Galios fields (GF(2))** that have a *"perfect"* [kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) (with a little bit of a constant added) as the autocorrelation.

Comment: Hi Robert, what I meant to ask was relating to Welch bound and has been appropriately answered by D. Sarwate below.

Comment: you should give the answer a check mark, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\theta_a$ and $\theta_c$ respectively denote the maximum magnitudes of the off-peak or out-of-phase periodic autocorrelation functions and the periodic crosscorrelation functions of a set of $K$ sequences of length $N$ and energy $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x[n]]|^2 = N$. In a [seminal paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055219/?tp=&arnumber=1055219) published in 1974, Welch proved that 
$$\max\big(\theta_a, \theta_c\big)\geq N\sqrt{\frac{K}{NK-1}} \approx 
\sqrt{N}$$ and so $\theta_a$ and $\theta_c$ both cannot have value $0$; at least one of them must be as large as $\sqrt{N}$. This shows that it is not possible to have uncorrelated sequences with perfect autocorrelation, just as the OP heard somewhere.

In a [follow-up paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1056116/) in 1979, I showed that
$$\left(\frac{\theta_c^2}{N}\right)+\frac{N-1}{N(K-1)}\left(\frac{\theta_a^2}{N}\right) \geq 1$$
which allows one to study the autocorrelation and crosscorrelation maxima separately, and gives additional insights into the problem.

- If $\theta_a = 0$ (all $K$ sequences have ideal autocorrelation functions), then $\theta_c \geq \sqrt{N}$. An example of such a set is the Frank-Zadoff-Chu sequences which have perfect autocorrelation functions and maximum crosscorrelation $\sqrt{N}$.
- If $\theta_c = 0$ (the $K$ sequences are uncorrelated, i.e., orthogonal for all cyclic shifts), then $\theta_a \gtrapprox K$. In particular, a set of $N$ uncorrelated sequences of length $N$ has $\theta_a = N$.  An example of such a set of sequences is the rows of a $N\times N$ DFT matrix. It is, of course, trivially true that a set of $K>N$ sequences of length $N$ cannot be orthogonal to each other, let alone be uncorrelated.

Similar results (but not the examples) hold for the *aperiodic* (or linear) correlation functions. For details, see my paper cited above.

Comment: Very nice summary, especially the examples you gave in the additional insights. I learned something new today; I wasn't aware of those specific relationships between the autocorrelation and cross-correlation properties.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate. I had a look through your paper earlier as I am working on creating a "close-to-perfect" aperiodic sequences. However, the explanation you have given here has helped me understand your findings (then) and the question I asked (now). Appreciate your response.

Comment: @Sal For aperiodic autocorrelations, look at the _impulse-equivalent sequences_  of Huffman mentioned in my paper cited above.